# ggsave without saving only last plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I'm using ggsave() function to save my ggplots but I have a little problem with that. It occurs that my ggsave() is saving only my last plot (so for example if I have 6 side by side plots I have only saved last one). I know that it's not a problem, because ggsave by default is saving last plot, but I cannot find how can I change it to save all plots.

To summarize :

```
library(gridExtra)
grid.arrange(qplot(1:10,1:10),qplot(1:10,1:10))
ggsave(file=random.png)
```

what I want to have :

[image]

what I have :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ggsave` default `plot` argument is `last_plot()`, you can change it and give your saved plot.

```
library(gridExtra)
temp <- grid.arrange(qplot(1:10,1:10),qplot(1:10,1:10))
ggsave(file='random.png', temp)
```

Comment: Perfect! Simply and efficient!